# Autohotkey to search images

Tags: cpu, autohotkey, gaming, ocr, steam

I'm learning how to use autohotkey and I wanted to create a script which open a game from steam and joins automatically to a specific server. My code so far is:

```
F1::
Run, steam://rungameid/346110
Sleep, 15000 <--- This is more or less the time that my computer takes to load it, and I want another way to check if the game is already loaded
MouseClick, left, 156, 520 <--- (Position of "JOIN ARK")
Sleep, 1500 <--- This is the time that takes to load the button (JOIN LAST SESSION) also I want to check this with another more efficient way
MouseClick, left, 746, 940 <--- Click the button "JOIN LAST SESSION"
return
```

So with this code I run the game, and join the last session. My meta is to make a loop which does:

1- Open Game if it's not open. If it's open, restart it.

2- Check when the menu appears and click the "JOIN" button located at x,y(156,520).

3- Check when the button "JOIN LAST SESSION" appears and click it.

4- If some popup appears (I have screenshoots for all errors), go to point 1.

I was thinking about OCR but don't know how to implement it with autohotkey.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to your problem is to use the 'ImageSearch' function.

If you hit print screen button whenever those popups occur, you can then CRTL+V paste it into paint. Then, crop the image so that all you have is your popup window and save it as .bmp file. You can then use this bitmap file within your ImageSearch code.

A quick look at someone's ImageSearch code can be found [here](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/100718-imagesearch-to-find-and-click-an-image-that-pops-on-random-times/).

So if your script finds the image it's looking for you can outline further code to run under 'ErrorLevel = 0'

If your script cannot find the image you can outline different code to run under 'ErrorLevel = 1'

it's advisable that at this point you start labelling your sections of code and making use of 'Gosub' so your code can jump between routines when it hits different 'if' variables. This way you don't need to create a giant script repeating yourself too much.

Also be aware that ImageSearch will not function properly when your script is transferred from one machine to another if the screen resolution is even slightly different. If you try to run your code on a machine that has a different screen resolution, you will have to screenshot your popups again for it to work.

Example:

```
    ImageSearch, FoundX, FoundY, 40,40, 300, 300, C:\My Images\test.bmp

if ErrorLevel = 2
    MsgBox Could not conduct the search.
else if ErrorLevel = 1
    MsgBox Icon could not be found on the screen.
else
    MsgBox The icon was found at %FoundX%x%FoundY%.
```

Comment: i've edited my question ^^ I like the answer but still cannot reproduce it

Comment: I'm still trying it but ImageSearch doesn't seems to work @Myles

Comment: @J0ki the ImageSearch function should work for you as long as your code is correct. The best way to test you're doing it right is to create a very basic script that searches for an image on your screen, and if found or not use the 'msgbox' function to throw up a message for both ErrorLevel = 1 and 0 variables. Also, the AHK community will be able to help you modify your code so it works. They're a great bunch and will often let you know exactly where you're going wrong when you paste in your code for them to see.